# When I run the user form I get Sub script out of range error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which is validating the data entered on user form with a static list of refernce data present in one of teh sheets on the excel .

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim iExit As VbMsgBoxResult
i = 0
LastRow = 0


LastRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("H1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To LastRow
  If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)) = Trim(TextBox1.Text) Then
    Exit For
End If
Next i


If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)) <> Trim(TextBox1.Text) Then

iExit = MsgBox("Invalid Customer ShortName ,Confirm if you want to ignore", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Data Entry Form")

If iExit = vbYes Then
Cancel = False
Else
Cancel = True

End If
End If

End Sub
```

issue :
I keep on geting Subscript out of range error intermittently on this line :

LastRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("H1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Some time the code works sometimes does not .

Comment: Then there is no worksheet in the active workbook named `sheet1` or there is no data in H1.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner ,  do  I need to refer to active workbook by using   Worksheets("sheet1"). activate ?  I do have a sheet1 which I have renamed as 'data' . But as I said I get this message sometimes .

Comment: If you renamed it then it is no longer named `sheet1` and so the line should be: `LastRow = Worksheets("data").Range("H1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`